# Why should I prefer float over flexbox?

Tags: css

I am new in front end design and when I was looking information about this I found 2 techniques about positioning: *float* and *flexbox*.

My question is: What should I use more? I'm oriented in mobile design too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [this great article](http://blog.karenmenezes.com/2014/apr/13/floats-inline-block-or-display-table-or-flexbox/) sums up:

---

**Floats**

*Advantages*

- Most popular way to lay things out; most grid frameworks follow this.
- Everyone's aware of float bugs due to the popularity of floating, and there are well documented ways to overcome them.

*Disadvantages*

- Need to be cleared. Can be quite painful if you're changing widths at 2-3 media query breakpoints, because the floats will need to be cleared that many times.
- No vertical centering
- No equal heights
- No source order independence

*Use for:*

- Large layout blocks that don't need equal heights and vertical centering

---

**Flexbox**

*Advantages*

- Source order independence. Could be of tremendous value for responsive layouts and eliminates the need for JS for this.
- Vertical centering
- Equal heights
- Flex boxes move along interchangebly the X and Y axis, with such ease, that you can really change things around with a couple of properties.
- Boxes grow and shrink, can be columns or rows, fit to the available space however you wish to declare this.
- There are multiple ways to do the same thing with flexbox.

*Disadvantages*

- Syntax is initially unintuitive. You spend the first few hours looking at demos saying WOW, followed by WTF.
- I've been noticing weird cross browser inconsistencies [...]
- A deep understanding of Flexbox takes a while. Once the layout gets more complex, or you add a couple of divs, things can get confusing. I'm going to document this more in an article.
- Lots of vendor prefixes, with a different syntax for older IE and Webkit. Use something like Autoprefixr to work around this. Or write some mixins. Or do something..
- Doesn't work on IE9. If you don't have to support IE9, you're fine.
- Reports of the older syntax impacting performance. I wouldn't care too much about this honestly, especially if you were using JS to do the things Flexbox now can...

*Use for*

- You can already start using it for vertical centering, if you don't need things to look the same on IE9.
- If you don't need IE9 support, it's perfect for source order independent layouts, equal heights.
- I would highly recommend using it for personal projects.
- App layouts where things need to stretch and squish. Flexbox really shines here.

---

So to recap', **flexbox** is the modern way, very powerfull but harder to learn. As it is kind of new, there is also a lot of bugs and it is not seemlessly compatible. **floats** are the old way: it is more basic, but easy to use.